# How to add dynamic code inside of a React Router Link component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to be able to add some dynamic code inside of the Link component.

I am trying to do this:

```
<Link to="/users/{{user.id}}/locations" className="nav-link">Locations</Link>
```

This currently doesn't work, the resulting HTML contains the {{user.id}} in the href attribute, so it isn't getting parsed.

I have tried single and double curly braces, no effect.

Comment: you should use es6 string templates. so it will be like below
`/users/${user.id}/locations`
use back ticks. for more details os ES6 string templates https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @MohitTilwani If I do that I get this error ```SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (119:59)```

Comment: my bad. you have to enclosed it in single curly braces
{`/users/${user.id}/locations`}
Everything between curly braces should be in back ticks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
let userId = {user.id}

<Link to={`/users/${userId}/locations`} className="nav-link">Locations</Link>
```

Note: those are backticks, not single quotations. If you don't want to use ES6, you can do something like the following:

```
var userId = {user.id}

<Link to={ "/users/" + userId + "/locations" } className="nav-link">Locations</Link>
```

Comment: when I do the backticks I get this error ```SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work:

```
<Link to={`/users/${user.id}/locations`} className="nav-link">Locations</Link>
```